# google map shows so many errors

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I try a google map application but i got error on it.pls help me to solve that...
This is my main activity code.In this i got so many errors.
Main Activity:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        GoogleMap googleMap;
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-33.796923, 150.922433);

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("My Spot")
                .snippet("This is my spot!")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));


        //  googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
      //  googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
       // googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));

    }


}
```

This is my manifest file.here i have no problem.
manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlev2map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlev2map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlev2map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlev2map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
              <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyBLt82HMLfp3PGJQoHG5_bCpyCQX_imlE0"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Paste the LogCat output, where the problems are visible. Thanks

Comment: is the key you are using for debug mode or release mode, and which apk are you checking debug one or release one?